# Split branch into two (per file)

Tags: git

I want to split a git branch into two branches, since it contains two unrelated features, which need individual review and merge.

I want selectively move changes from some files into a new branch.

Comment: `git branch branch-1; git branch branch-2`.   After those 2 commands, you have 2 branches at the same ref.  Now do as you wish with them.

Answer (score 1):

First create a new branch:

```
git checkout main

git checkout -b new-branch
```

The take some changes from the orig-branch:

```
git checkout --patch orig-branch foo.py
git checkout --patch orig-branch bar.py
...
```

```
git commit
```

Remember: We want to **move** the changes, not copy them.

```
git show > ~/tmp/new-branch.patch
```

Now unapply the changes which went into the new branch.

```
git checkout orig-branch
git apply -p0 --reverse ~/tmp/new-branch.patch
```